# Attempting to breathe some new life into my old macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, restore

I have an older MBP and it seems to be on its last legs.  It crashes regularly and someone suggested doing a "destructive restore."

My question is: how do I start from scratch and only reinstall the stuff I want?  I do use Time Machine, but I don't want to do a complete reinstall because that'll still reinstall the same programs that are over-burdening/corrupting the computer in its current state.  I'm big on changing program defaults to suit my needs, so I would want to keep preferences in programs like MS Word.  I also no longer have disks for some of my programs, so I need to reinstall important programs from backup.  And perhaps most important, I have things like work Exchange email accounts that took a while to get tweaked to work correctly; I'd love to be able to restore and find all of the server settings completely the same.

Any advice?

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want to do a non-destructive "destructive restore". That is kind-a-impossible sir.

Answer (score 0):

You state:

> I also no longer have disks for some of my programs, so I need to reinstall important programs from backup

If you no longer have the disks for some of your programs, you only have two options.

1. Create a new user account, then migrate your data over using the data migration assistant. While not as reliable at cleaning up junk as a format, creating a new user account can alleviate some funky issues.
2. If you have Mountain Lion, hold CMD + R while rebooting, and select "Reinstall Mac OS X". After the install, restore your data from your time machine backup. Your programs should still be there, but the OS will be like new.